# OleDb data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, excel, types, oledb

I'm currently trying to write into an excel file. I use this piece of code:

```
    public void UpdateExcelFile(string dir, string sheet, string sql)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Format("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='{0}';Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0;MAXSCANROWS=0\";", dir));
        MyConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MyConnection.Close();

        if (myCommand != null)
        {
            myCommand.Dispose();
            myCommand = null;
        }

        if (MyConnection != null)
            MyConnection.Dispose();
    }
```

I'm getting an "data type mismatch in criteria expression" exception. My statement looks as follows:

```
string cmdString = String.Format("Insert into [{0}] (Customer, Location, CalendarWeek, from, till, [agreed at], [agreed with], [{1}]) values('{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}')"
                    , sheetName, getPackaging.Text, getCustomer.Text, getLocation.Text, getCalWeek, getFirstDayOfCalWeek,
                    getLastDayOfCalWeek, getDateOfAgreement.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), getNameForPrice.Text, getPrice.Value.ToString());
```

So everything is converted to string. In my Excel file I have every single column converted to "standard". Why does this happen? I even have the MaxScanRows property set to 0.

EDIT: 
Here is the cmdString

```
Insert into [Sheet1$] (Customer, Location, CalendarWeek, from, till, [agreed at], [agreed with], [10x500]) values('A','City','1','02.01.2016','08.01.2016','05.03.2016','Test','3')
```

Comment: The **from** field may be giving you problems. Wrap it in square brackets to avoid cross-association with SQL's **from**. e.g. `(Customer, Location, CalendarWeek, [from], till, [agreed at], [agreed with], [{1}])`

Comment: No this is not the problem. I have just translated the column names into english for better understanding.

Comment: Can you show `cmdString`